# Provide pre-configured PostgreSQL, XYZ, and WMS connections to docker install of QGIS

Tags: qgis, docker

I'm creating a custom docker image for Kasm (https://kasmweb.com/) of various GIS software. For the QGIS install, I would like to include the appropriate database connections, WMS, and XYZ tile services for the users so they don't need to recreate those every time they log on.

I see on my local version of QGIS these connections live under the user profile. Within Ubuntu that would be `/home/user/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/QGIS3.ini`

Would it be as simple as COPY-ing over a QGIS3.ini file to the correct directory?

Comment: probably, have you tried it to see what happens?